# Formula to identify where there is a value for '0' and '1' per date in Excel pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, time

I am analysing camera trap data looking at nocturnal denning sites. I have formatted my data so that I have a '0' value and an '1' per date when there is an animal entering and leaving a den site on the same day (ie; one 'sleep event'). I am currently manually going through my pivot tables counting each occasion where there is both an entering (0) and exiting (1) event on the same day to count how many times an animal 'slept' in the den site. Im hoping there is a quicker way but have no idea how to do that... This is what my pivot table looks like: enter image description here

Any assistance would be appreciated :)

Comment: This needs `COUNTIFS()` but there is no screenshot attached